# processing textarea field input with php

Tags: php

I need a function to prosses my textarea field input before I save it in my database.

Textarea field input:

```
Hi
sahdj sdhjsdj f hasjhf ash dsdhasd hjsdhjashdhsadj sjsadhjsdhjhassdnsdnnjas
Thanks
```

I want to make it look like this:

```html
Hi<p></p>sahdj sdhjsdj f hasjhf ash dsdhasd hjsdhjashdhsadj sjsadhjsdhjhassdnsdnnjas<p></p>Thanks
```

Just want to replace line break with a `<p></p>`.

Comment: This requires `output only` formatting `nl2br();` not database formatting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button.

Comment: @Waygood How did I not know about `nl2br()`...?! I always did it manually (so thanks!)

Comment: `preg_replace("/\r?\n/", '<p></p>', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br` will only replace newline characters with `<br />`. On most of my sites I want to wrap the lines in `p`-tags. You could achieve this this way:

```
$lines = explode("\n",$_POST['textarea_name']);
$output = '';
foreach ($lines as $v) {
    $output .= '<p>'.$v.'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the HTML use the strip_tags() function against the $_POST variable from the textarea's name attribute in the HTML. e.g.:

```
$textarea_input = strip_tags($_POST['html_name_attrib']);
```

[The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) gives more info on that function. If you're talking about protection against SQL injection use the real_escape_string function for mysql or mysqli. Info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and example:

```
$protected_value = $mysqli_conn->real_escape_string($_POST['html_name_attrib']);
```

Did that answer your question?

You're not talking about using `str_replace("\n", "<br/><br/>", $_POST['html_name_attrib'])` to simply change the soft line breaks with HTML line breaks are you?

Comment: I think you mean using `$array = explode("\n", $_POST['html_name_attrib']);` and then `foreach($array as $line){ $string .= '<p>' . $line . '</p>'; }`